# Bower to Npm Migration

Tags: npm, npm-install, bower

I have an old project that is using Bower and Npm toghether. Currently trying to get rid of Bower but I'm stuck.

The project has a postscript in package.json where it was running "bower install", as well as having a .bowerrrc file with a "directory" configuration. This was used to install the dependencies under a specific location.

The current structure would look like this

myProject
--bowerClasses
--node_modules
--src
...

The question is how I can reproduce this Behavior using only npm, or how I can use the node modules in my html file?

Note I have all previously bower dependencies in "dependencies" (those would need to move from node modules)
And other npm dependencies in "devDependencies" those can stay in node_modules.